# Slicers Excel Web App not Working

Tags: excel, mashup, slicers

The excel web slicers no longer appears it started on 22.6.2016.
The slicers appear white, does not show errors.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix?

thanks

Comment: here's a question too [link]http://www.excelmashup.info/forums/topic/slicers-are-not-working/

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context? I can use slicers just fine in Excel Online.

Comment: Here is an example of the slicer error

[link]http://www.jrossetto.com.br/excel-web-app.html

the slicers appear white, with only the edge

when I change the language of the web to excel English, it works. But to share via javascript it does not appear

Comment: I can see the slicers and I can use the slicers just fine. I'm using Chrome on Win10.

Comment: Here for me it does not appear, it must be something about the language of the script. Because when I change the onedrive to English, excel in web it works, but when using the sharing via javascript, it pulls by default pt-BR script.

To me it looks like this: [link] http://www.jrossetto.com.br/error-excel-web-slicers.jpg


Is there any way to set javascript to English?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by forcing the script to pick the default language as English, adding value “&ui=en-US”

link to solve http://www.excelmashup.info/topic/slicers-are-not-working/#post-1333

Comment: You should add that as an answer to your own question and accept it, so others can see the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by forcing the script to pick the default language as English, adding value “&ui=en-US” link to solve excelmashup.info/topic/slicers-are-not-working/#post-1333